# Is it possible to specify a user agent in a rails integration test or spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

I was doing this before in a rails 2 app in a `ActionController::IntegrationTest` with

```
get '/', {}, {:user_agent => "Googlebot"}
```

but this seems to not work anymore in Rails 3.

What should I do?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you use request.user_agent in your application, you can write the following code:

```
get '/', headers: { "HTTP_USER_AGENT" => "Googlebot" }
```

Comment: Awesome - do you know of any way to set this for all requests made during integration tests?

Comment: Can you elaborate why passing symbols doesn't work anymore? This seems to be a step back from a syntactic point of view, and an unnecessary migration hassle when porting from 2.x.

Comment: Also, passing the header as HTTP_* didn't work for me either. I had to pass it as CONTENT_TYPE instead of HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE. If I passed XML as the request body, only CONTENT_TYPE => application/xml would make Rails parse it into the params hash.

Comment: This doesn't work with Rails 3.1. The third argument to `get` specifies a session hash, not HTTP headers.

Comment: You won't be able to set `remote_ip` that way

Answer (score 15):

None of the above answers worked for me, the following is what finally worked in an rspec controller test:

```
@request.user_agent = "a MobileDevice/User-Agent"
post :endpoint, param: 2354
```

Comment: undefined method `user_agent=' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 13):

I was able to get it working on Rails 5.2.1 using this:

```rb
get '/path', headers: { 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (blah blah)' }
```

I looked [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/feefcb869e4418d2ec366ae8a9149ac7a4ef2a39/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb#L215) for the acceptable keywords to the method.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this behavior and with Rails 4.0 you will be able to specify actual HTTP Headers like "User-Agent" and "Content-Type" in integration and functional tests. There no longer a need to specify them as CGI variables.

If you are interested you can have a look at the change: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9700

Answer (score 4):

For myself, in a controller test in rspec3, I used

```
request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] = "Hello"
```

Before making the request

Answer (score 3):

If you have a collection of specs which all require a specific user agent, you may find the following helps to DRY up your specs:

Define this somewhere (e.g. `spec_helper.rb`):

```
module DefaultUserAgent

  def post(uri, params = {}, session = {})
    super uri, params, {'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => MY_USER_AGENT}.merge(session)
  end

  def get(uri, params = {}, session = {})
    super uri, params, {'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => MY_USER_AGENT}.merge(session)
  end

end
```

Then just `include DefaultUserAgent` when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

A user agent is just an http header, so you should be able to use the methods here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#helpers-available-for-integration-tests

And pass in the user agent to the headers (I didn't test this):

```
headers = {"User-Agent" => "Googlebot"}
request_via_redirect(:get, '/', {}, headers)
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing. `request.user_agent` in my controller returns nil. If I do the same experiment against the running app, it returns the user agent.

Comment: did you try request.headers['User-Agent']