# Testing mobile views for a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, rspec

In a rails app, if I use a different request format for mobiles. e.g. render *.mobile.erb. What are the best practices to write tests for this? I use RSpec and can't find information on how to force it to render mobile views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean view specs (as opposed to integration tests)?  RSpec2's `render` method delegates to `ActionView::Base#render` so you can pass :file, :template, :format, etc to `render` in your view specs.  A better approach would probably be to just specify the correct view when describing the spec like so (example ripped form RSpec2's website):

```
describe "events/index.mobile.erb" do
  it "renders _event partial for each event" do
    assign(:events, [stub_model(Event), stub_model(Event)])
    render
    view.should render_template(:partial => "_event", :count => 2)
  end
end
```

For integration tests you will need to set the user-agent.  Here is a link to another question that addresses changing the user-agent (it's the same for RSpec): [Is it possible to specify a user agent in a rails integration test or spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383971/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-user-agent-in-a-rails-integration-test-or-spec)

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer but just change the user-agent of the request's headers to a mobile's User-agent