# How to set HTTP_USER_AGENT in rspec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to specify a user agent in a rails integration test or spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383971/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-user-agent-in-a-rails-integration-test-or-spec)

I'm testing a request in my rails app using rspec. I need to be able to set the user agent before the request.

This is not working:

```
  describe "GET /articles feed for feedburner" do
it "displays article feed if useragent is feedburner" do
  # Run the generator again with the --webrat flag if you want to use webrat methods/matchers
  @articles=[]
  5.times do
    @articles << Factory(:article, :status=>1, :created_at=>3.days.ago)
  end
  request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'feedburner'
  get "/news.xml" 
  response.should be_success
  response.content_type.should eq("application/xml")
  response.should include("item[title='#{@articles.first.title}']")
end
```

end

How can I properly specify the user agent?

Comment: If you're going to mark a question as a duplicate mightn't it be a good idea to link to the duplicate?!

Answer (score 13):

Try using this in your test:

```
request.stub!(:user_agent).and_return('FeedBurner/1.0')
```

or for newer RSpec:

```
allow(request).to receive(:user_agent).and_return("FeedBurner/1.0")
```

Replace `FeedBurner/1.0` with the user agent you want to use. I don't know if that exact code will work but [something like it should](http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/stubs.html).

Comment: I didn't have any luck with this, even calling it immediately before `post`, I still had `request.user_agent == nil` in the controller. Could you post a more complete example?

Comment: In recent Rspec, `request` is nil.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do in an integration test - notice the last hash that sets REMOTE_ADDR (without HTTP_). That is, you don't have to set HTTP header before the request, you can do so as part of the request.

```
# Rails integration tests don't have access to the request object (so we can't mock it), hence this hack
it 'correctly updates the last_login_ip attribute' do
  post login_path, { :email => user.email, :password => user.password }, { 'REMOTE_ADDR' => 'some_address' }
  user.reload
  user.last_login_ip.should == 'some_address'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Define this somewhere (e.g. `spec_helper.rb`):

```
module DefaultUserAgent

  def post(uri, params = {}, session = {})
    super uri, params, {'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => MY_USER_AGENT}.merge(session)
  end

  def get(uri, params = {}, session = {})
    super uri, params, {'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => MY_USER_AGENT}.merge(session)
  end

end
```

Then just `include DefaultUserAgent` when you need it.