# Use request method in rspec request specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test a scenario between several controllers with rspec.

I think "request specs" is the method I should use.

The main problem is that I use the request environment to log in with Basic Authentication.

My controllers tests works well :

```
describe ClientsController do
  context "With a confirmed user" do
    before(:each) do
      @password = "bidon-bidon"
      @user = ...
    end

    it "should create session" do
      request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials(@user.login, @password)
      post :create
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

But when I use the method `request` into my file `spec/requests/scenario_spec.rb`, it raise an exception:

```
describe "My scenario" do
  context "With a confirmed user" do
    before(:each) do
      ...
    end

    it "should do several things"
      request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials(@user.login, @password)
      post :create
      response.should be_success

      ... some calls to other controllers
    end
  end
end
```

The `request` method seems to return `nil`.

```
NoMethodError:  undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
```

My questions are:

- Where can I find documentation about `request` method ?
- How can I set it ?

I'm using Rails 4 with Rspec 2.14.7.

Comment: It's because you don't write your spec in context of controller, like in first case.

Comment: @MarekLipka I need to write a scenarion between several controller contexts... How can I set different requests ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from this question - [Is it possible to specify a user agent in a rails integration test or spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383971/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-user-agent-in-a-rails-integration-test-or-spec)

Try:

```
it "should do several things"
  post :create, {}, 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials(@user.login, @password)
  response.should be_success

  ... some calls to other controllers
end
```