# How to include http headers in integration tests (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, http-headers, integration-testing

I'm trying to write an integration test for my API. The request being made is:

```
delete sessions_path, session: { article_id: @article.id}
```

The request should however also include http headers:

```
Authorization: "mytoken"
My_email: @user.email
```

How to include these http headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
delete sessions_path, {session: { article_id: @article.id}}, {"Authorization" => "mytoken", "My_email" => @user.email}
```

You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383971/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-user-agent-in-a-rails-integration-test-or-spec) for more informations.

Comment: Thanks, I had searched but hadn't found the answer. It worked using `delete sessions_path, {session: { article_id: @article.id}}, {"Authorization" => "mytoken", "HTTP_MY_EMAIL" => @user.email}`.